# Breusch-Pagan Lagrange multiplier (LM), Hausman tests

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, hausman, breusch-pagan

I'm working with panel data and want to decide which model I should use: pooled OLS, Random effects, or Fixed effects. When I run the Breusch-Pagan Lagrange multiplier (LM), it says pooled OLS is preferred. Yet, according to Hausman Test, the Fixed Effect model is preferred. Should I rely simply on BP test and proceed with pooled OLS in this case?